# How to pass data to another page using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem on ajax call.

Here is my code regarding the ajax:

```
$('#Subjects').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../portal/curriculum.php',
        data: 'studentNumber='+$('#StudentID').val(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#curriculum').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

When I echo `studentNumber` on another page, the `studentNumber` is `undefined`. Why is that?

Comment: Use `{ studentNumber: $('#StudentID').val() }`

Comment: Agree with Jake, I would also place a "console.log($('#StudentID').val()) just before the ajax call to see whether it has the expected value.

Comment: You may also want take a look at the doc [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I have change the data but still it is undefined. i also use console.log it has a value. i dont know what i've done wrong.

Comment: How are you accessing studentNumber in the other file?

Comment: Please show the HTML regarding this.

Comment: In curriculum.php you should be able to access it by $_POST['studentNumber']

Comment: Are you really sending what you think you are? Check the networking tab in your console.

Comment: yes it works already. seems that my problem is with the echo.. i didnt use $_POST in echoing the result i just echo studentNumber, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Simply modify your code like this:

**JS**

```
$('#Subjects').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../portal/curriculum.php',
        data: { studentNumber: $('#StudentID').val() },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#curriculum').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $var = $_POST['studentNumber'];

?>
```

If you still can not make it works.. other things you should consider..

```
url: '../portal/curriculum.php',
```

1) Please use full URL `http://yourdomain.com/portal/curriculum.php` or absolute path like `/portal/curriculum.php`

2) Add an error callback to check out the error message

```
$('#Subjects').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../portal/curriculum.php',
        data: { studentNumber: $('#StudentID').val() },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#curriculum').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it works already. seems that my problem is with the echo.. i didnt use $_POST in echoing the result i just echo studentNumber, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("test1.php",
        {
          name: "Makemelive Technologies",
          city: "Mumbai"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The above will make a call to test1.php and its code will be

```
<?php

$fname=$_REQUEST['name'];
$city= $_REQUEST['city'];

echo "Company Name is ". $fname. " and it's located in ". $city ;

?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: please check it now.. if this helps you..i think there is a mistake in your call to ajax..

Comment: yes it works already. seems that my problem is with the echo.. i didnt use $_POST in echoing the result i just echo studentNumber, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#Subjects').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../portal/curriculum.php',
      data: { studentNumber: $('#StudentID').val() },
      success: function(data)
       {
        //here data is means the out put from the php file it is not $('#StudentID').val()
        $('#curriculum').html(data);
       }
      });
    });
```

as exsample if you echo some text on php it will return with data  $('#curriculum').html(data);

try to change

```
//change
success: function(data)
{
   $('#curriculum').html(data); 

//to 
success: function(result)
{
   $('#curriculum').html(result);
```

check what will happen. 
post us php file too curriculum.php

Comment: yes it works already. seems that my problem is with the echo.. i didnt use $_POST in echoing the result i just echo studentNumber, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use through Jquery,Ajax and php

step 1. index.php

```
<div id="div_body_users">
</div>
<form method="post" id="frm_data" action="">
<input type="button"  id="target" name="submit" value="submit">
<input type="key" id="key" name="key" value="1234">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#target" ).click(function() {
//  alert("test");
  var frm_mail = document.getElementById("frm_data");
  var frm_mail_data = new FormData(frm_mail);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/test.php",
      data: frm_mail_data,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
             document.getElementById('div_body_users').innerHTML=result;
        }
    });

 });

});
</script>
```

step 2. create test.php

```
  <?PHP

 //print_r($_POST);

if($_POST['key']=='1234'){
    echo "success";
    exit(0);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "view/logintmp.php?username="+username+"&password="+password,
}).done(function( msg ) {
    var retval = printmsgs(msg,'error_success_msgs');
    if(retval==1){
        window.location.href='./';
    }
});
```

Comment: Mind providing some explanations about how this code help compared to other answers?